# Unknown column 'Username' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_select_db($database_binary, $binary);
$query_account = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_account, "text"));
$account = mysql_query($query_account, $binary) or die(mysql_error());
$row_account = mysql_fetch_assoc($account);
$totalRows_account = mysql_num_rows($account);

$maxRows_trade = 20;
$pageNum_trade = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_trade'])) {
  $pageNum_trade = $_GET['pageNum_trade'];
}
$startRow_trade = $pageNum_trade * $maxRows_trade;

$colname_trade = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_trade = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_binary, $binary);
$query_trade = sprintf("SELECT * FROM asset WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_trade, "text"));
$query_limit_trade = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_trade, $startRow_trade, $maxRows_trade);
$trade = mysql_query($query_limit_trade, $binary) or die(mysql_error());
$row_trade = mysql_fetch_assoc($trade);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_trade'])) {
  $totalRows_trade = $_GET['totalRows_trade'];
} else {
  $all_trade = mysql_query($query_trade);
  $totalRows_trade = mysql_num_rows($all_trade);
}
$totalPages_trade = ceil($totalRows_trade/$maxRows_trade)-1;

$maxRows_withdrawreq = 10;
$pageNum_withdrawreq = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_withdrawreq'])) {
  $pageNum_withdrawreq = $_GET['pageNum_withdrawreq'];
}
$startRow_withdrawreq = $pageNum_withdrawreq * $maxRows_withdrawreq;

$colname_withdrawreq = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
  $colname_withdrawreq = $_SESSION['Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_binary, $binary);
$query_withdrawreq = sprintf("SELECT * FROM withdrawal WHERE Username = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_withdrawreq, "text"));
$query_limit_withdrawreq = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_withdrawreq, $startRow_withdrawreq, $maxRows_withdrawreq);
$withdrawreq = mysql_query($query_limit_withdrawreq, $binary) or die(mysql_error());
$row_withdrawreq = mysql_fetch_assoc($withdrawreq);
```

I am getting an error:

> Unknown column 'Username' in 'where clause'

How can I solve it?

Comment: post your users table schema

Comment: Table structure for `users`
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `SN` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `FirstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Balance` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `docName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `idfront` varchar(200) ,
  `idback` varchar(200) 
)

Comment: What about structure for asset and withdrawal tables?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Table structure for table `asset`
--

CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `Asset` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `optiontype` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Invested` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Entry Rate` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Rate` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Entry Time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Expiration Time` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Returns` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Customer` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;

Comment: @ajovi4ever Please edit your question to include chunks of code like that. Stamping it into the comments makes it very hard to read. You should also avoid using MyISAM for anything mission critical: It's not journaled, it does not support transactions, and it suffers badly under heavy write activity due to table locks.

Comment: Table structure for table `withdrawal`
--

CREATE TABLE `withdrawal` (
  `id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Customer` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Amount` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;

Comment: Please move table structures into the question, rather than posting in comments.

Comment: @tadman I am sorry I don't how to do that yet, thanks guys for your help cause I am stuck.

Comment: @ajovi4ever It's okay if you're new. Just try and follow the format as best you can. Move that code over to your question and delete the comments as those are just clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset and withdrawal tables do not have a column called Username. So add that column to these tables or change WHERE condition in the sql statement related to these tables.These sql statements refer to the Username column in the WHERE clause that does not exist:

```
SELECT * FROM **asset** WHERE **Username**

SELECT * FROM **withdrawal** WHERE **Username**
```

New CREATE statements including Username column:

```
    CREATE TABLE asset ( Asset varchar(100) NOT NULL, optiontype varchar(200) 
NOT NULL, 
    Invested varchar(200) NOT NULL, Username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Entry Rate varchar(200) NOT NULL, Rate varchar(200) NOT NULL, Entry Time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Expiration Time varchar(200) NOT NULL, Status varchar(200) NOT NULL, Returns varchar(200) NOT NULL, Customer varchar(200) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;

CREATE TABLE withdrawal ( id varchar(100) NOT NULL, Username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Customer varchar(200) NOT NULL, Amount varchar(100) NOT NULL, currency varchar(100) NOT NULL, email varchar(100) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=armscii8;
```

Comment: Can you please help me update the asset and withdrawal table schema?

Comment: OK will add to my answer

Comment: Added CREATE statements with Username as per users table.

Comment: I have included the username column now I am getting    Column 'Asset' cannot be null error

Comment: This is different to the origjnal question, so please mark this question as answered and raise a new question specific to this new error.

Comment: Thanks you have really helped me solve this problem I now know why I am getting the new error. Thanks Once more.

Comment: Please remark as answered, I think you may have toggled unanswered again by mistake?